# JavaScript btoa() to Python b64decode().decode("utf-8")

Tags: javascript, python, encoding, base64

In JavaScript, I encode these 2 strings:

```
btoa("test") // "dGVzdA=="
btoa("testà") // "dGVzdOA="
```

Then in Python:

```
base64.b64decode("dGVzdA==").decode("utf-8")  # "test"
base64.b64decode("dGVzdOA=").decode("utf-8")  # error...
```

The first one works. The second one throws this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position
>   4: unexpected end of data

How can I retrieve `"testà"` in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://base64.guru/developers/javascript/examples/unicode-strings). This seems to work:

```
btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent("testà")))
```